# Grouping and partially transposing a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, transpose

I want to group a dataframe by a column (Type) and then transpose the columns (Parameter 1-3) while keeping the group as shown in the exemplary tables. While the first step is clear, i'm struggling with the parameter transposition and don't know how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated...

| Type | Parameter 1 | Parameter 2 | Parameter 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 10 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 9 |
| B | 4 | 8 | 2 |

| Type | Params | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Parameter 1 | 1 | 3 |
|  | Parameter 2 | 2 | 10 |
|  | Parameter 3 | 4 | 1 |
| B | Parameter 1 | 2 | 4 |
|  | Parameter 2 | 5 | 8 |
|  | Parameter 3 | 9 | 2 |

Comment: @mozway, should be reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, unpivot by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and last [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(g = df.groupby('Type').cumcount().add(1))
        .melt(['Type','g'], var_name='Params')
        .pivot(index=['Type','Params'], columns='g', values='value')
        .add_prefix('Value'))
print (df1)
g                 Value1  Value2
Type Params                     
A    Parameter 1       1       3
     Parameter 2       2      10
     Parameter 3       4       1
B    Parameter 1       2       4
     Parameter 2       5       8
     Parameter 3       9       2
```

Or [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Type', df.groupby('Type').cumcount().add(1)])
        .stack()
        .unstack(level=1)
        .add_prefix('Value')
        .rename_axis(['Type','Params'])
        )
print (df1)
                  Value1  Value2
Type Params                     
A    Parameter 1       1       3
     Parameter 2       2      10
     Parameter 3       4       1
B    Parameter 1       2       4
     Parameter 2       5       8
     Parameter 3       9       2
```